# Javascript For Loop Causes Unexpected Behaviour

Tags: javascript

Code Sample A

```js
var isPrime = function (num) {
    //for(i = 1; i <= num; i++) {}
    if(num === 2){
      return true;
    }
    return false;
};


var sumPrimesUpTo = function (num) {
    
    for(i = 1; i <= num; i++) {
       console.log(isPrime(i));
    }
    
};

sumPrimesUpTo(5);
```

So we have a function that supposedly checks for a prime number and a second function that sums prime numbers up to a provided number. When you run this it outputs.

```
false
true
false
false
false
```

Now we have the same code sample but with the for loop in isPrime uncommented.

```js
var isPrime = function (num) {
    for(i = 1; i <= num; i++) {}
    if(num === 2){
      return true;
    }
    return false;
};


var sumPrimesUpTo = function (num) {

    for(i = 1; i <= num; i++) {
       console.log(isPrime(i));
    }
   
};

sumPrimesUpTo(5);
```

This outputs

```
false
false
false
```

I don't seem to get why the for loop changes the output?

Comment: You're using a **global** `i` variable in both functions.

Comment: use `let` (or `var`) to declare your variable: `for(let i = 1; i <= num; i++)`

Comment: Thanks nicholas, you saved me from hours of debugging. Changed the second for loop to j and it worked.

Comment: @AdamWinnipass That's not a solution, that's a bad workaround. The real solution is to stop using global variables.

Comment: avoid use global variable, better to use `let`

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org//docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Instructions/let

Comment: It would be nice if javascript just used a global keyword to declare global variables.

Comment: @AdamWinnipass No. If it did that, you couldn't diagnose typos in variable names (hello, Python/PHP). JavaScript did the right thing with `'use strict';`.

Answer (score 5):

`i` is scoped globally, you should use `let` to keep `i` scoped to the `for` loop.

You could use `var` as well but `let` is a better choice because it will give you the scope you want and also not allow it to be re-assigned in this block.

```
var isPrime = function (num) {
    for(let i = 1; i <= num; i++) {}
    if(num === 2){
      return true;
    }
    return false;
};


var sumPrimesUpTo = function (num) {

    for(let i = 1; i <= num; i++) {
       console.log(isPrime(i));
    }

};

sumPrimesUpTo(5);
```